# build a voice calling app that can that directly call local/international phone number

Tags: mobile, sip, voice, calling-convention

i am currently working on a mobile app that allows users to call local phone number directly, typical app that does something like this are Boss evolution, Yolla, Talk-360,
I don't know if there is any voice-api-service that provides such service, i have tried Twilio, but what i found out is that twilio can't place a call and start conversation directly. has anyone tried something like that before?. please you suggestions and recommendations are welcome.